# shell-script mode: set local vars for indentation

Tags: file-local-variables

I have a shell script that uses 2-space indentation, like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function foo() {
  echo "Hello world"
  echo "Nice to see you $1"
}

foo Tony
```

Emacs default indentation for shell is 4-space. I have been trying to specify local variables to change the indentation to 2-space, but failed. This is the extra stub I added at the end for the script above (that did not succeed):

```
# Local-variables:
# sh-indentation: 2
# sh-basic-offset: 2
# End:
```

Before doing this local variable thing, I tried to customize emacs using `Programming` -> `Languages` -> `Sh` -> `Sh Script` -> `Sh Indentation` -> `Sh Basic Offset`. If I set this variable to 2, and open the shell script, it did indent that script to 2-space.

On the other hand, the exact same Emacs could do it for a Python script, simply with this kind of stub at the end of that Python script:

```
# Local-variables:
# python-indent: 2
# End:
```

Can someone help me through this?

Wirawan

Comment: Have you tried replicating the problem without any init file (`emacs -q`). This issue could be caused by some hook running when the file is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a space instead of a `-` between `Local` and `Variables:`

Comment: Thank you for spotting my typo! Couldn't believe I did not catch that small error!

Comment: @WirawanPurwanto Note that you can use `M-x add-file-local-variable` and it will generate those comments for you (if they don't already exist), as well as giving you tab-completion for the variable name.